# INSERT INTO MySql Syntax error SqlWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, delimiter, sql-insert

I have a query that MySql Workbench says returns an error of a missing semicolon.  I looked on here, and the general conscensus was that changing the deliminater will solve the problem becuase of workbench's built in process.  However, when I change the delimiter to $$, the syntax error just moves from the VALUES (p_IPAddress) line to the END line.  The error is still missing a semicolon, even though the delimiter is now $$.

```
    DELIMITER $$

USE woodsweb$$

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateNewSession
(
    IN p_IPAddress VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SessionLog (IPAddress)
    VALUES (p_IPAddress);

    SELECT last_inserted_id()
END$$
```

Comment: Nevermind.  I was so wrapped in the delimiter issue I never realized that there was no semicolon at SELECT last_inserted_id();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the semicolon BEFORE the END statement.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE woodsweb$$

CREATE PROCEDURE CreateNewSession
(
    IN p_IPAddress VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SessionLog (IPAddress)
    VALUES (p_IPAddress);

    SELECT last_inserted_id();
END$$
```

Note the added `;` after **SELECT last_inserted_id()**